# Does pagination removed from Coinbase wallet library in Python?

Tags: python, django, coinbase-api

Update:
I have tested the returned value before and after the pagination, it seems like they have removed the pagination without changing the docs yet.

I am using the Coinbase API to retrieve a list of accounts. According to the official documentation, I expected the response to include a pagination object alongside the data array. This pagination object is crucial for handling data systematically, especially when dealing with large datasets that require efficient navigation through multiple pages.

Issue Encountered:

However, in my recent interactions with the API, the responses lack the pagination object, and instead, only the data array is returned. This deviation from the documented response structure is causing significant issues in data handling and application functionality.

Examples of Responses:
Response from my Application:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "allow_deposits": true,
      "allow_withdrawals": true,
      "balance": { "amount": "0.00000000", "currency": "BIGTIME" },
      "created_at": "2023-11-22T17:19:42Z",
      ...
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Expected Response (Based on Documentation):

```
{
  "pagination": {
    "ending_before": null,
    "starting_after": null,
    "limit": 25,
    "order": "desc",
    "previous_uri": null,
    "next_uri": null
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "58542935-67b5-56e1-a3f9-42686e07fa40",
      "name": "My Vault",
      ...
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Does any one have this issue or their is some issue with the old implementation?

Solving the problem of the pagination.

Comment: did you check all values in data from API? Python keeps it as dictionary so values can be in different order - so it may have `pagination` after `data`. Maybe you should check keys in dictionary - `your_data.keys()`

Comment: in question you could add link to documentation.

Comment: @furas Thank you, I have test the returned value before and after the pagination, it seems like they have removed the pagination without changing the docs yet.

Comment: https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/commerce/docs/pagination